# item.Recycle returns an empty GUID (SharePoint Online, C#)

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

So, long story short, I want to delete (recycle) an item, save its ID, and then restore it from the trashcan using that ID.

I can recover an item from the trashcan by name, like so:

```
if (rItem.leafname == "torecycle.docx")
    {
        rItem.restore();
        client.executequery();
    }
}
```

But that requires the user to know the name of the item beforehand.

When an item is recycled and moved to the trash, its Id changes. The `item.Recycle()` method is supposed to return a `ClientResult<Guid>` with the new Id of the `RecycleBinItem`, but the returned `Guid` is empty (all zeroes).

I recycle the item like this:

```
if (item.DisplayName == "torecycle")
{
    client.Load(item);

    var recycledItem = item.Recycle(); 
    var newGuid = recycledItem.Value;

    Console.WriteLine("new guid " + newGuid);

    Client.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

The print out is `new guid 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`, but it does move the recycle bin item to the trash bin properly.

Am I missing something here? How can I get the actual Guid of the `RecycleBinItem`?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: this is strange behavior, msdn speaks for itself it should return valid GUID of 'a new item in the recycle bin'. Have You tried to debug this? Does sharepoint has the file in recycle bin after calling the method?

Comment: the `.Value`, is it because the guid is a `Nullable`, or because `newGuid` is actually of type `ClientResult<Guid>`?

Comment: @Tatranskymedved Yeah, it does recycle the item properly, despite the empty Guid. I updated the original post to include that bit!

Comment: @dlatikay I updated the first post to make it a bit clearer. Yeah, basically `Recycle()` returns a `ClientResult<Guid>` but the `.Value`. should give a Guid.

Comment: [MSDN for ClientResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539241(v=office.14).aspx) -> it is just wrapper for sending data across network.

Comment: Are You able to obtain item's `GUID` after the `Recycle()` when accessing the file directly in the bin?

Comment: run `ExecuteQuery` first, then read the value. does this already solve the problem?

Comment: @dlatikay Yess, I moved the `ExecuteQuery` between `var recycleItem` and `var newGuid` and it works now! Thank you so much to you both for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value of the `Recycle` function is a `ClientResult<T>`, which is just a wrapper for the underlying SOAP request/response model. Requests are collected locally and sent when `ExecuteQuery` is called. Therefore result values will only be populated after that call finished.

To understand this difference between the SharePoint server and client object models, it is necessary to look at the [overall concept](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee535262(v=office.14).aspx), because in the documentation of [ClientResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee543385(v=office.14).aspx), it is never mentioned.